# How to move app from background to foreground in ionic 2?

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

Is there any method to move app from background to foreground when a `push-notification` arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do such this by `push notification` you need something like direct `video call` or `voice call` try `Voip`.  Maybe you find it useful for what you need.